# Why is יה אלי before Ashrei and הנני העני after?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, yom-tov, song-poetry

At least in Nusach Ashkenaz, there is a piyut before Musaf on the 3 regalim, יה אלי, and one on Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur, הנני העני.

However, in every shul I've been to, יה אלי is said before Ashrei of Musaf, while הנני העני is after Ashrei (and after putting back the Sefer Torah), right before kaddish.  Why the difference in placement?

Comment: What do you mean by "before Musaf"? I wouldn't say "יה אלי" is before Musaf unless you mean it in the sense that פסוקי דזמרא is before Musaf. יה אלי is a piyut designed to precede Ashrei. It has nothing to do with Musaf as far as I can tell.

Comment: @DoubleAA As much as יה אלי directly references Ashrei, it's clearly targeting Musaf of Yom Tov rather than Ashrei itself, otherwise why not say it at Mincha?  (Shacharit you'd get into hefsek issues.)

Comment: You could say it at Mincha if you want (or any other time of day/year). Just people aren't into Piyutim at Mincha so much. It is not at all clearly targeting Musaf except in your head. There is nothing about it that targets Musaf other than your association with it as the start of the Musaf Chazzan.

Comment: @DoubleAA אתיצבה לקראתך?  You can sit for Ashrei (and I remember seeing someone say that you should).

Comment: Just making this up on the fly, but the הנני tefila is seems to clearly be going on the _hazan_'s tefila on behalf of the congregation. There is often a long break between _ashrei_ and _shmoneh esrei_ for the rabbi to speak, so it seems like we would want to say that piyut in close proximity to the _chazan_'s tefila, which would mean after the rabbi finishes speaking.

Comment: Is הנני העני a Piyut? It doesn't seem like it. It just seems like a prayer the Chazzan says to himself. Nothing to do with the community. He's just about to start the hard part so he prays for success.

Comment: @DoubleAA Just to be clear - I'm not saying it would make sense to say the text as we have it after Ashrei, of course it's designed to lead into Ashrei.  I think that it's primarily targeting Musaf (and I know you disagree - although Artscroll doesn't, they call it in English "pre-Musaf piyut"), so I'm asking why it's written that way, as distinct from הנני העני.  Actually I would find before Ashrei to be the more logical place.

Comment: @Heshy You have no reason to think that though. And we both know there's nothing significant in Artscroll's English headings. So your question has no basis at all. There is literally no reason to think these two passages are related, similar, parallel, correlated or in any other way serve like purposes.

Comment: @DoubleAA you haven't convinced me.  What Artscroll says doesn't mean that I'm correct, but it does mean that at least one other person thinking about the structure of tefilla reached the same conclusion as I did.  I've given you an argument that it can't apply only to Ashrei, אתיצבה לקראתך, and I haven't seen any counter from you.

Comment: There's also no way for me to prove whether​or not this applies to neila since it comes before neila (various months before). I think you are deeply confused about the burden of proof here.

Comment: @DoubleAA why would you say before Ashrei that you're going to stand?  Simple question.

Comment: Maybe where the paytan lived they stood for ashrei? Maybe the chazzan there would? Maybe it's a figurative usage? You can ask that and I doubt we'll find anything but speculation, but anyway that's no reason to think this Piyut is or should be parallel in any way shape or form to Hineni from RH/YK. People write piyutim for all sorts of occasions based on what they feel inspired by. (And I'm still not admitting hinneni is a Piyut at all.)

Comment: You seem to think there's a category called"pre musaf piyutim" and that these are two instances of this with a notable difference in placement which must be based on some first principle. Really there's no such category. Just two things: an ashrei Piyut and a prayer before musaffor the chazzan. Even if yah Eli was intended to be about the upcoming musaf too that doesn't change anything. There is no reason at all to expect these two things to be at the same point in the service.

Answer (score 3):

`Koh Keli is a poem/prayer which is made specifically as an introduction to Ashrei. That is why it is said before Ashrei.

You can tell this is so, because each of the paragraphs of Koh Keli end with "...Forever I will praise you with Ashrei Yoshvei Beysecha." The poem asks that we all be returned to our land and be able to offer the proper korbanos etc. Ashrei's first words are "Happy are those who dwell in your house..". So it is appropriate to precede Ashrei with a request that "Your house" be rebuilt so we can all return there etc.

Koh Keli is a "pre-mussaf" prayer because Ashrei is the usual pre-mussaf prayer/intro and Koh Keli introduces Ashrei. It was intended to get the community to keenly feel the lack of the Temple and the Land of Israel which is the only place to offer the real musaf korbanos. **The one who wrote the piyut seemed to want the congregation to cultivate this in mind during the words of Ashrei so they would already have such a feeling flaming in their heart as Musaf started.**

Hinneni he'ani... means "Behold I am a poor man...". It is the Chazzan's job to be the people's representative to lead the Musaf prayer. This job starts with the Kaddish before Musaf (which is after Ashrei). You need a Chazzan to recite Kaddish and everyone answers. Ashrei doesn't need a Chazzan.

So, right before the Chazzan begins his job, he declares how unworthy he is and begs Hashem that his and the congregation's prayers are accepted etc.

That's the difference. :)

Comment: The OP seems irrationally convinced Kal Keili is about Musaf, so as silly as the question is, I don't see how your asserting otherwise is going to convince him.

Comment: @DoubleAA :) Well maybe my experience as Chazzan for both for many years would help him believe me?

Comment: First he'd have to believe that you actually have ever been a Chazzan...

Comment: What you stated about "Kah Keli" is sensible. But, this really needs a source or two to strengthen this answer. I'd imagine that the Art Scroll Machzor, among other sources, should say something that supports your points.